# How to get XDP program into kernel with iproute2?

Tags: ebpf, iproute, xdp-bpf

I am using "ip link" command to put xdp program into kernel, in my virtual machine(kernel-version:4.18)

command like this:

```
 ip link set dev ens33 xdp obj xdpsock_kern.o sec .text
```

but after this command, the error said:

```
No ELF library support compiled in.
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems like your `iproute2` version was not built with libelf support. You may need to compile it yourself. Ensure that `libelf-dev` package is installed before building `iproute2`

Comment: this problem is fixed.
reconfigure iproute2

Comment: Glad to hear. Please share your fix for future readers. You can post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by reconfigure the iproutes.

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git

cd iproute2/
./configure --prefix=/usr

make
sudo make install
```

Update: Now hosted at https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2.git